# How to get started with LAMP?

Tags: php, lamp

I have 1 year exp in web development field. I have only worked in windows environment. Recently I got an offer to attend an interview at a MNC for the post of PHP developer, but they are working in LAMP platform. So they told me to expect some questions from that area. Acually I know nothing regarding LAMP. My belief was that php development in any platform is same. So, anyone please tell me, how to get aware in LAMP. Please tell me also the technical difference between WAMP and LAMP.

Comment: a·ware Adjective /əˈwe(ə)r/: *Having knowledge or perception of a situation or fact.* You gain knowledge by working with LAMP (install Linux, set up Apache/MySQL/PHP). Your perception will grow when read or hear about LAMP. What have you tried so far?

Comment: i have installed linux mint and tried to setup LAMP, but it was not sucess.

Comment: @blessed then you need to go back and try it again. My answer (hopefully) gets you an environment where this is easy to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Honestly, the best thing to do is setup a virtual machine running something like [CentOS](http://www.centos.org/) and building a LAMP stack using it. There are plenty of guides out there on how to accomplish it, but I recommend you take snapshots frequently (particularly, take a snapshot of your VM after the initial install) and get to the point where you can set it up in your sleep. This will help you get a base understanding of the server aspect.

[Here's a quick guide to get you started.](http://www.howtoforge.com/quick-n-easy-lamp-server-centos-rhel) I recommend using [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) for your VM host.